# Fetch blob image displays broken image

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, blob

I am saving image from interface form to `MYSQL` in two ways , one way i encode image to Base64 the second way i save image as it is , but both when i fetch image i get broken image .

1st way using base64 :

```
    ...
     if (isset($_POST['photo'])) {  
 $photo =  $_POST['photo'];
 $photoValue = base64_decode($photo);
$sql = "INSERT INTO students (photo) VALUES ('$photoValue')
....
```

Result i get whe i display it to echo :

`imagesjp`on :`echo base64_encode( $result['photo']);` and broken image  on :`cho '<img src="data:photo/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['photo'] ).'"/><br/>';`

second way when i saved image without encode it to base64 :

```
     ...
        if (isset($_POST['photo'])) {   
    $photo =  $_POST['photo'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO students (photo) VALUES ('$photo ')
     ....
```

Results i get on the interface when i display it to echo:

`aW1hZ2VzLmpwZw==` with :`echo base64_encode( $result['photo']);` broken image  on :`cho '<img src="data:photo/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['photo'] ).'"/><br/>';`

But when i upload image to mysql manually when i fetch this image comes up well but the problem is very huge and slow to use it , the result i get can fill entire page when it's one image. Results on `echo base64_encode( $result['photo']);`  **IS:**   `/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL ...`

Comment: Why do you down vote me ?

Comment: Warning: your code is vulnerable to **SQL injection**. Do not concatenate data with your SQL, use parameterized queries.

Comment: Also, unless you know your files are going to be very small all the time, I strongly recommend you save the pictures as files rather than in your database. That way you can even serve them like any regular file.

Comment: @jcaron understood, but to save it as file produces the big size in mysql there is another way i can save it as fire but with a reduced size ?

Comment: That’s the whole point: if you save it as a file it won’t go into your MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Try $_FILES variable 
`$_FILES['IMAGE NAME']`

Comment: Yes let me try and see

Comment: I finally get nothing in mysql when i use your technic